# How to cancel navigation on specific page UWP and show message dialog prompt

Tags: uwp, navigation, prompt

I am trying to have a message dialog prompt on a certain page where user can enter their information. However, I would like to have a prompt to remind the user that the information are not saved if they are trying to exit the page by click on the navigation bar when on that specific page.

My navigation bar is a like a frame shared with many pages, hence I have no idea how to "cancel" and navigation and show a prompt message.

For now I am trying to put the codes for the prompt under OnNavigatedFrom.... the page got navigated when I click on anything button on the navigation bar, and the prompt message does shows. Which is not what I wanted. How can I do it? Thank you.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        navigationHelper.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
        idleTimer.Stop();

        MessageDialog clickMessage;
        UICommand YesBtn;
        UICommand CancelBtn;

        clickMessage = new MessageDialog("The photo has not been sent. Are you sure you want to cancel the request?");


        YesBtn = new UICommand("Yes", delegate (IUICommand command)
        {
            idleTimer.Stop();
            var rootFrame = (Window.Current.Content as Frame);
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(HomePage));
            rootFrame.BackStack.Clear();

        });

        CancelBtn = new UICommand("Cancel", delegate (IUICommand command)
        {
            idleTimer.Stop();
            var rootFrame = (Window.Current.Content as Frame);
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), "SendPhoto");
            rootFrame.BackStack.Clear();
        }

        );
        clickMessage.Commands.Add(YesBtn);
        clickMessage.Commands.Add(CancelBtn);
        clickMessage.ShowAsync();

    }
```

Comment: By saying shared frame, do you mean you've enabled AppViewBackButtonVisibility property? If so, have you tried this event: Windows.UI.Core.SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested

Comment: Hi, nope.. I didnt enable AppviewBackButtonVisibility property... I created my own navigation bar at the side of my pages